# How to get a Win32 program to update the file size while still writing files

Tags: windows, file, winapi, stdio

I have a Win32 program that keeps a file open and writes data to it over a period of several hours.  I'd like for the file size, as shown in an Explorer window, to be updated every so often.

As an example, when a browser is downloading a large file, you can see the file size change over time, even though the file is still downloading.

With my current naive implementation, the file size remains zero until I close the file.

How do I do this in Win32?  Currently the file is open using `std::ofstream`.  Is this a proper application of `std::ostream::flush()` ?  Or do I need to close and reopen the file with some regularity?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ostream::flush()` makes sure you have your data safe on disk. Flushing the buffer is a valid use case in situations where the automatic flushes ain't good enough for you (e.g. there's too little data written over too long periods, the data is written constantly but needs to be accessible constantly too, you need to be sure the data gets logged in case of crash or power down etc.); yet, on some OS/filesystem combinations (see [Why is the file size reported incorrectly for files that are still being written to?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813)), that still won't update the file size accordingly. On Win32, you usually won't see size updates before actually closing/reopening the handle; sometimes re-reading the dir etc. will help, and sometimes it simply won't.

As such, you can use e.g. [ReOpenFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/aa365497(v=vs.85).aspx) to force that update, or simply use close/open instead of flushing. The exact solution depends whether you **need** the updated filesize so direly and the reduced output rate is not a real problem (in which case reopening is the best option), or if you can live with a wrong size reported (in which case flushes are your best option IMO).

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I just needed to hit F5 to refresh the Explorer window.  I tried flush() and the reopening trick, and although those didn't hurt anything, it still required me to manually refresh Explorer.